# php.ini file missing but php.ini-dist & php.ini-recommended are there

Tags: php

I've been trying to find the php.ini file. I ran phpinfo() and the location shows as: C:\WINDOWS. In the Windows folders there are only php.ini-info and php.ini-recommended files. [image: php]

Could the file be in another location?

I need to configure the file so I can get a contact form on a website working. (Set smtp settings). Version is: PHP 5.0.4 running on Windows NT.

If there is another way to send the contact form fields to an email, I would consider that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't neccessarily mean it's *loading* from that dir, it just means it's *looking* in that dir. And there's no such file there. No biggie -- typically you'd just copy `php.ini-recommended` to `php.ini` and edit as desired for your tastes.

Note: relying on local mail delivery is usually a pain, especially for Windows where you don't normally have an SMTP service handy. I'd recommend using a mail service API like Mailgun instead. It will give you all sorts of nice features like reporting and  bounce detection.

> Version is: PHP 5.0.4 running on Windows NT.

Er, really? That is legitimately ancient and almost certainly full of security issues. You'll probably want to upgrade / replace it ASAP.

Comment: Got you. I'm not too familiar with php so I didn't want to assume the same info could go from ini-recommended to .ini. I'll give this a go. I'll also look into Mailgun, thanks. Ref it being outdated. That is just the tip of the iceberg. I've started a new job and everything is legitimately outdated. The website I'm replacing hasn't been touched since 2001.

Comment: Note -- if this site has been running since 2004 with no `php.ini` file in place, putting one there might change some existing behavior, or possibly take the site down.

Comment: Cheers! I've read up on Mailgun, I'm going to go that route most likely.